# Colored elements in a sentence lose their color when they are in span

Tags: javascript

First I change color in two words of a sentence. Then I wrap all the words of the sentence in a span but the color of the two words disappears. Could you please someone explain me what I am doing wrong?

```js
   // First I change color in two words of a sentence
k1 = document.getElementById('Example').innerText;
k1 = k1.replace('my own', `<span class="color">my own</span>`)
document.getElementById('Example').innerHTML = k1;

// Then I wrap all the words of the sentence in a span
// but the color of the two words disappears
k2 = document.getElementById('Example').innerText.split(/\s/);

// wrap each word in a span
var word = '';
var content = '';

for (word of k2) {
content += `<span>${word}</span> `;
}
document.getElementById('newExample').innerHTML = content;
```

```css
.color {
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id='Example'>This is my own example</div>
<div id='newExample'></div>
```

Comment: `innerText` only gets text, not html.

Comment: I change color in text and then put it back in HTML. Am I wrong ?

Comment: Yes because then you do `innerText.split()` and lose that span you just inserted

Comment: I understand what you are telling me but I don't know how to resolve it. Anyway thank you for your time.

Comment: This is a very hard problem. Either you use `innerText` and you lose pre-existing HTML markup, or you use `innerHTML` and you have to deal with the spaces that belong to the markup itself. Depending on what you want to accomplish, you should find another way of doing it.

Comment: I think you are right. I was afraid of such an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **Short answer:**

If you want to get the content of a node while keeping all the tags, you're looking for [**outerHTML**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML).

From what you're trying to achieve, however, it looks like you might benefit more from using [**childNodes**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes).

Here is the [**working code**](https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-lederberg-4n005?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) in the sandbox.

---

### **Problem:**

The innerText property will keep only the text inside of a node:

> **HTMLElement.innerText**: A DOMString representing the rendered **text content** of an element. ([From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText))

That means it will strip the element of all tags (and its attributes, including class names).

So you're not **wrapping** these new elements in a span tag, but rather **copying their content** to newly created span tags that don't have the class name. And effectively loosing the class name previously set.

---

### **Solution 1:**

Use outerHTML to get a string representation of the node's HTML. This will keep all the tags, including their attributes (and thus, classes). The side effect of this is that you can no longer split this string at every space character to get only the meaningful words; you'd get all of the tag's characters as well.

Separating words and words enclosed by tags can be done via a regular expression like this:

```
(<\s*\w+?[^>]*>.*?<\s*\/\s*\w+>|\w+|[!?@#$%*.&]*)
```

[Working example](http://regexr.com/581pu)

Regular expressions can get tricky. They give you a lot of control over how you can separate, capture and manipulate characters, but they can look meaningless at first.

You might not need it, though. If all you want is to wrap in a span each word from a sentence (be it styled by a tag or not), I would recommend using childNodes:

---

### **Solution 2:**

childNodes is a read-only property that returns a NodeList of all child nodes of the given element. Text inside of an element is also considered a node (a **text node**), and tags are **element nodes**. There are quite a few [nodeTypes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType), but those two are the most relevant ones for your example.

The strategy here is to:

1. Use childNodes to get a list of the contents of your element, including text and tags;
2. Separate pure text nodes from the text that is inside of other tags;
3. Text nodes are not split into words automatically, so we still need to split them;
4. Wrap each of the split words in a span element;
5. Wrap each tag in a span element

This is how the code would look like:

```
let k1 = document.getElementById('Example').innerText;
k1 = k1.replace('my own', `<span class="color">my own</span>`)
document.getElementById('Example').innerHTML = k1;

let nodeList = document.getElementById('Example').childNodes;
let content = '';
for (let i = 0; i < nodeList.length; i++) {
  if (nodeList[i].nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
    const splitText = nodeList[i].nodeValue.split(/\s/);
    splitText.forEach(piece => {
      content += `<span>${piece}</span> `;
    })
  } else {
    content += `<span>${nodeList[i].outerHTML}</span> `;
  }
}

document.getElementById('newExample').innerHTML = content;
```

**Here is a sandbox with the [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-lederberg-4n005?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark).**

Comment: Thank you a lot for your concern, your detailed answer and above all your time.

Comment: I've tested the solution of R Simioni and works like a charm. Excellent contribution !!!

Comment: Thanks for your kind words!

Answer (score 1):

Use innerHTML so that you keep the markup, but then instead of just splitting by `/\s/`, add some more information to your RegEx so that it ignores spaces inside a HTML tag. We can do this using a negative lookbehind, searching for an `<` character which comes before the space, given that there are no close tag `>` characters in-between. This would look like:

```
/(?<!<([^>]*))\s/g
```

When we call

```
k2 = document.getElementById('Example').innerHTML.split(/(?<!<([^>]*))\s/g);
```

We end up with an array split only at spaces inside the actual text. This, however, has split your two words at the space between them, so you will see something like:

```
["<span class='color'>my","own</span>"]
```

Note: it is important to use single quotation marks for `'color'`, as it will become a nested string. 
Therefore, in the for loop, we need to complete the other half of the tag:

```
for (word of k2) {
if(word){
  if(word.endsWith("</span>")){
     content += "<span class = 'color'>" + word; // add the open color span to the beginning
   }else{
      if(word.endsWith("<span")){
         content += word + "</span>"; //otherwise, close the color span
      }else{
         content += `<span>${word}</span> `; // otherwise, wrap it in a normal span
      }
   }
}
}
```

Edit: after testing, I found that this particular regEx returns an `undefined` element when it splits at a space. This doesn't affect the other elements, it just means that we need to check if `word` is defined before we add it to content. See modified code above

Comment: Thank you a lot for your solution.